# Upload on server image html2canvas

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, nginx, html2canvas

[image]I have this js :

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'ajaxfile.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {
        image: base64URL
   },
   success: function(data){
       console.log(data);
       $.notify("info", "Upload successfully");
   },
   error: function () {
       $.notify("Error on image upload");
   }
});
```

PHP code :

```
<?php
  $image = $_POST['image'];
  $location = "src/upload/";
  $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $image);
  $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
  $filename = "screenshot_".uniqid().'.png';
  $file = $location . $filename;
  file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);
  return [
     'status' => true
  ]
?>
```

The call is done (I saw in browser console) but on console.log I have the code php returned. Seems that nothing happen, the code php is not implemented. Have you an idea ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english

I put an image with the error

Answer (score 0):

`file_put_contents()` returns `false` on failure, so you could assign it to a variable and use that to determine your status like so:

```
<?php
    $image = $_POST['image'];
    $location = "src/upload/";
    $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $image);
    $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
    $filename = "screenshot_".uniqid().'.png';
    $file = $location . $filename;

    $imageData = file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);

    if ($imageData !== false) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        http_response_code(500);
        die();
    }
?>
```

Comment: @HareaCostea what do you mean you "get all the php code"? The screenshot shows an XML parsing error.